# I want to create a login for my php page -its connect with database but not working properly

Tags: php, mysqli

I want after successful of my login its open a `Home.php` page automatically.

my database name is `relieffoundation` which is created in wampserver locoalhost. Table name is `admin` its is directly show it else part that is uername and password not matched

```
<div id="user_login_div_input">
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Username'])) {
    $user = $_POST['Username'];
    $pass = md5($_POST['Password']);

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect to the database!' . mysqli_errno());
    }
    $selectdb = mysqli_select_db($con, 'relieffoundation') or die("Could not select DataBase");
    $query = "SELECT *FROM admin where username = '$user' AND password= '$pass'";
    if (mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, $query))) {
        echo "Login successfull";
        header("location : Home.php");
    } else {
        echo "Uername and Password not match!";
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
LOG IN
<form  id="myForm" name="myForm"  method="post">      
    <input class="input" type="text" id="Username" name="Username"  placeholder="Username" required="">
    <input class="input" type="password" id="Password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" required="">
    <button id="login" type="submit" > Log In</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Take a look at these functions: [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)
[`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) -- and what exactly happens when you run this code? What do you wish to happen?

Comment: Your problem may be in `mysql_connect()`, takes 4 paramters refer to php manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php, Where is your database name?

Comment: @Manee.O.H -- OP selects his database after, so that doesn't really make any difference.

Comment: @NADIM Is the password `md5`-hashed in the database? Are the columns named exactly `username`  and `password`?

Comment: i dont get any error.. just it show me the else part.. that is "Username and password not matched"

Comment: if (mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, $query))) {
        echo "Login successfull";
        header("location : Home.php");
    } else {
        echo "Uername and Password not match!";
    }

Comment: please check here if (mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, $query))>0) you didnt check for total number of rows greater than 0.

Comment: @RahulSingh `if (0) { /* false */ }` and `if (1) { /* true */ }`, so it works like that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have

```
$query = "SELECT *FROM admin where username = '$user' AND password= '$pass'";
```

you need a space between * and FROM

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM admin where username = '$user' AND password= '$pass'";
```

Comment: Strictly isn't necessary, the SQL *should* get parsed regardless. Makes for cleaner code, though!

Answer (score -1):

try to remove ' in query 
`$query = "SELECT *FROM admin where username = $user AND password= $pass";`
or try concatenation
`$query = "SELECT *FROM admin where username ='". $user."' AND password='". $pass.'";`

Comment: If those variables are strings (which they are), that quote is necessary. And breaking out of the query to pass variables isn't doing any difference either.